# Iterating through a list of acceleration to calculate final velocity and then usign the answer as the initial velocity of the next

Tags: python, modeling

I am new to coding and am trying to gain a graph of speeds as acceleration varies. (i have coded the drag force on a car (values from CFD) and at varying speeds, this drag force changes.)

I have a 2000 term list of acceleration varying as drag varies at different speeds and I now am trying to use suvat to calculate the final velocity at each iteration takes over 0.01m.

starting from 0, I want the code to use V^2 = U^2 + 2as to find the final velocity(V) and then use this final velocity for the next acceleration term in the list and so on until the end.

Example:

```
acceleration = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
u = 0
a = acceleration


def step_final_velo(u=u, a=a, s=0.01):
    step_v = []
    count = 0
    for i in a:
        count += np.sqrt(u ** 2 + (2 * i * s))
        step_v.append(count)
    return step_v
```

Comment: velocity is acceleration times time.  You have to add up all of the tiny velocity changes.  The discrete sampling probably introduces systematic errors, so you might want to investigate ways to mitigate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully get the question but here is my interpretation

```
import math
acc=[1,2,3,4,10,2]
output=[]
#set all the suvat
s=0.01
u=0
v=0
a=0
t=0
for i in range(len(acc)):
    #v^2=u^2+2as
    a=acc[i]
    x=u*u+(2*a*s)
    v=math.sqrt(x)
    u=v
    v=0
    output.append[u]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
import math
acceleration = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
u=0
s=0.01
final_velocity=[]
for a in acceleration:
    v=math.sqrt(u**2+2*a*s)  # v**2=u**2+2*a*s
    final_velocity.append(v)
    u=v
print(final_velocity)
```

**Output:-**

```
[0.1414213562373095, 0.2449489742783178, 0.34641016151377546, 0.4472135954999579, 0.5477225575051661]
```